# Foreign Key field always showing up as None in views.py, but not empty in database

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that I want set up to have a worksheet object that has a list of section objects, where each section object has a list of answers.

In the excerpt from my **views.py** shown below, I am trying to pass the first section associated with a worksheet to the render function.

Whenever I get an individual section object in the following function within my **views.py** file, the section object does not have any answers associated with it. However, I know that the section I have gotten *does* have answers associated with it, because when I do a GET request (or look using the browsable API that is automatically setup by django rest framework), I can see that the section with the same id as the one I have in the function shown below in **views.py** has a long answers list as one of its attributes.

Despite this, when I print out section.answers as shown below, myapp.Answer.None is displayed.

**views.py**

```
def worksheet_detail(request, pk):
    worksheet = Worksheet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    sections = Section.objects.filter(worksheet=worksheet)
    sections = list(sections)
    section = sections[1]
    print(section.answers)
    print(section.id)
    return render(request, 'worksheets/worksheet_detail.html', {
        'worksheet': worksheet,
        'section': section,
    })
```

**models.py**

```
class Worksheet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default='')


class Section(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default='')
    worksheet = models.ForeignKey(
        Worksheet, related_name='sections', null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)


class Answer(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, 
                                    default='')
    num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='answers', 
                                null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('student_name', 'section', 'num', 'id',)

class SectionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    answers = AnswerSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        answers_data = validated_data.pop('answers')
        section = Section.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for answer_data in answers_data:
            Answer.objects.create(section=section, **answer_data)
        return section

    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ('name', 'worksheet', 'answers', 'id',)

class WorksheetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    sections = SectionSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sections_data = validated_data.pop('sections')
        worksheet = Worksheet.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for section_data in sections_data:
            Section.objects.create(worksheet=worksheet, **section_data)
        return section

    class Meta:
        model = Worksheet
        fields = ('name','id', 'sections')
```

Comment: Can you add value of section.__dict__ variable? Just want in what format it is showing..!

Comment: {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x10e7bcef0>, 'id': 20, 'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13, 0, 38, 34, 687214, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'name': 'Section 20', 'worksheet_id': 1}

Comment: The answers field doesn't even show up :/